# How to get ajax response in html select option

Tags: ajax

Hello every one I am working in laravel but today  I am stuck

please some one help me , iwant to get response from ajax inside select>option in html.
my modal is working perfectly. and other data like input fields text, date, file are perfectly shows but in select>option there is an error!

```
<script>

     function editJobs(id){
 
        $.get('/jobsEditRoute/'+id, function(response){

            
 
 
          $("#id").val(response.id);
          $("#job_titleE").val(response.job_title); 
          $("#apply_start_dateE").val(response.apply_start_date); 
          $("#last_dateE").val(response.last_date); 
          $("#a").attr("src","images/"+response.job_adv_image); 
          $("#job_descriptionE").val(response.job_description); 


           **$("#job_for_districtE").val(response.job_for_district);** 
        
           
          document.getElementById("job_for_districtE").innerHTML = "response.job_for_district";
         
          $("#editing_product").modal('toggle');
      //  alert(response.job_descriptionE);

        });
     }
  </script>
```

Current District

```
                     <option value="hlelo" **id="job_for_districtE"**></option>
                   
                     
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Swati iam facing the proble.  iwant to edit table data bootstrap modal and iwant to click the edit button and show  only that id data from database and shows in modal so other data are showing but iwant to show that data in select > option

Comment: Try `$("#job_for_districtE").text(response.job_for_district)` .

Comment: Not working swati

Comment: what exactly you need to do ? above code should work if id is same .

Comment: Dear Swati!  I want to edit my data through bootstrap-modal when I click on edit button of a specific record . then through id that record are shown from database and show in the bootstrap-modal form and i want to change from that modal. so every field shows data in that box like input field text imgsrc but only select>option not shows through that code .. my question is that how to show the the data in option through id

Comment: you need to show selected value which is present in db in your select-box ? If yes use select box id not option id then your current code will work.